# Displaying browser result using Java

Tags: java, html, browser

I'm a CS student taking Data Structures and Algorithms in Java.  Our first project involves debugging code that uses JSOUP to gather HTML code.  I don't know HTML and it was not a pre-requisite for the class...but I'm learning.  My question is this:  I'm gathering HTML results in a java Document; how do I launch a browser and displays these results?  I'm doing some research online but can't find anything...any help or direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Browsers and websites are much more complicated (especially nowadays) than simply downloading the HTML, so even if download the HTML and open it in a browser, if you’re not also downloading the CSS and JavaScript, it won’t look right (or it may not work at all).

Comment: I"m not sure...we were given a file and told to find the bugs and fix them.  The existing code has this:
//below will print HTML data, save it to a file and open in browser to compare
//System.out.println(doc.html());
it's commented out and obviously system.out.println isn't doing what the comment says it should.  So I'm assuming this is something we should be finding in the code that's wrong and we need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking this out to see if it will help - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/browser.html

Answer (score 0):

> we were given a file and told to find the bugs and fix them. The existing code has this:

```java
//below will print HTML data, save it to a file and open in browser to compare 
//System.out.println(doc.html());
```

> it's commented out and obviously system.out.println isn't doing what the comment says it should.

According to your comment, you should be able to "comment in" the `System.out.println` line, which will print the HTML to your terminal, etc. when you run your code:

```java
//below will print HTML data, save it to a file and open in browser to compare 
System.out.println(doc.html()); // Note, the '//' at the beginning is gone
```

The easiest thing to do would be to pipe this to a file directly, but if you're using Eclipse or something, that is more fiddly, so it might be easier to just copy paste it. Either way, you want something like this (in bash, assuming unix):

```
> javac MyProgram.java
> java MyProgram
<html><body><p>hello world</p></body></html>
> # copy HTML into file
> # or just pipe it in the first place
> java MyProgram > output.html
> # at this point, whether you piped it or copied it with your text editor, you should have an HTML document
> cat output.html
<html><body><p>hello world</p></body></html>
```

In such a scenario, then you could double click on `output.html` in your file explorer (or maybe use the `open` command) which should open it in your browser.

Comment: Thanks so much...I understand about the comments.  But when I uncomment the line the results are just shown in the Eclipse window...I would like them shown in a browser.  And unfortunately I'm not on Unix but Eclipse.  I'll keep fooling around with it and if I have more questions I'll let you know.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @WantaghMomma as I mentioned in the answer, probably the easiest thing to do from Eclipse is just to copy/paste the contents from the Eclipse window to a text file using your OS' text editor, save it as `myfile.html`, and then double click the file to open it with your default browser.